# Concurrency: HashMap and Lists as a value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronized, concurrenthashmap

Supposing I have a Synchronized HashMap, which has a String as a key and as **a List** as a value.

```
Map<String, List<Object>> map = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, List<Object>>());
```

Will that list be thread-safe? For example, if I do this:

```
List<Object> list = map.get("whatever"); // Supposing I get a List
list.add(new Object()); // Would this be thread-safe?
```

In case not, would it be with a ConcurrentHashMap, instead of a synchronized one? Or the only way to avoid race conditions is converting it into a CopyOnWriteArrayList?

Comment: No, only the `Map` is thread-safe, for both `synchronizedMap()` and `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: You are adding elements to the `list` object, which has nothing to do with the synchronized map, which just happens to contain it. The list itself would have to be a synchronized collection.

Comment: What do you do if the `Map` doesn't already have a `List` for the given key? You can't just call `map.put()`, because the world may have changed between the `get()` call and the `put()` call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collections.synchronizedMap would only provide thread safeness for the resulting map. If you want to make the map values thread safe why not decorate your lists like:

```
Collections.synchronizedList(yourList)
```

and then add them to the map?

Comment: I was expecting that, I just wanted to be sure about it, so I will make use of CopyOnWriteArrayList